# running 'run-app' command from hudson

Tags: grails

I have a grails application and have configured hudson for continous integration, in the grails plugin of hudson I've put run-app task which starts a tomcat container and deploys the app in tomcat.The problem I'm facing is - hudson itself is running in tomcat and when my run-app tries to start tomcat again it fails.
I then tried writing script which will create a war of my app and deploy it in tomcat, then how can i restart tomcat from hudson configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Does it fail because both Hudson and grails are trying to use port 8080? If so, then just modify your `run-app` command to use a different port:

```
grails -Dserver.port=9090 run-app
```